# view files recently restored from recycle bin

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, file-recovery, recycle-bin

I had an unsaved `.xlsx` file and after opening Microsoft Excel, I suddenly chose *No* to the recover suggestion of Microsoft Excel. I think the name of that file was `my_file_name (version 1).xlsx`

Then I opened recycle bin and clicked on that file and then clicked *restore selected item*. Now the problem is that I can't find out where the restored file has gone! Also when I open Microsoft Excel again, there is not the recover option anymore.

I also tried to search for the file with `my_file_name` query, but it cannot find the `my_file_name (version 1).xlsx` file.

Is there a way to view recently restored files in windows 7 and their current locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! I found it!
Such unsaved files will be in this path:

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel
```

So after restoration, the restored file will return back here.

Comment: Wait a bit (~48 hours) and you should be able to mark this reply as *Accepted*. Beyond a small boost to your own rep, it will benefit others looking for a solution to a similar problem. see [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Jeeped : Thanks for your attention, but accepting my own answer to my question will not boost my reputation.